# How do I downgrade Sqitch?

Tags: sqitch

I am running Sqitch on a Windows 10 machine. Using mysql 8.0.19.
I initially installed Sqitch using Strawberry Perl.

Every time I try to run verify scripts, the verify script fails. Every time my co-worker runs the same verify script on his machine that has Sqitch .9999 it works flawlessly.

We have both tried to diagnose the issue, and we have been able to narrow it down being a sqitch issue. As both our setups are the same except for the version of Sqitch we run. I am using the latest version of Sqitch 1.1.0.

What is the safest way to downgrade a CPAN module ? I have tried to use;

```
cpan install DWHEELER/App-Sqitch-v1.0.0.tar.gz
```

I have tried to force the install as well. With no luck.

The error I get when I try and run the above command;

```
Could not fetch authors/id/////////D//DWHEELER/App-Sqitch-v1.0.0.tar.gz
```

Please note the example I provide is for V1.0.0. as I try and see if the bug exists in 1.0.0 as well before I report it as a bug.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cpanm`, instead:

```
cpanm DWHEELER/App-Sqitch-v1.0.0.tar.gz
```